# Event name when IBOutlet is assigned in the controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, uikit

I would like to run some logic in my Controller class once all IBOutlets get assigned. What method do I need to override in the Controller class to receive this event?

Thanks,
Rui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-(void)awakeFromNib` method is called after the outlets are connected. There's a good article on it at [Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/26/cocoa-tutorial-awakefromnib-vs-applicationdidfinishlaunching/)